# How do I run a JAR file on an EC2 instance?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce

I wrote a basic MapReduce program on my MacBook utilizing Apache's resource here:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html

After I finished, I Exported a jar of my project and transferred it to my EC2 instance through SSH.

After that, I ran this command through the terminal of my EC2 instance:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar test.jar com.map.reduce games.tar.gz output
```

Where `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` is where hadoop is installed on the EC2, `test.jar` is the transfered jar file and com.map.reduce is the package name where all of my classes are hosted. `games.tar.gz` is the directory I will be working with and output is where I want to see my results.

But I am getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:311)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
```

I am wondering if this is an issue with the JARS I am using locally. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the command work locally on your machine? If so: does it still work if you move the `jar` to a different direcotry and execute the command there?

Comment: I actually forgot to do the .classWithMainMethod after my package name,

Comment: Of course, ClassNotFound means that your jar depends from other jars, that are not included in your AWS installation. How exactly are you exporting your jar? Note, if you use either maven or gradle then you can either create an "uber-jar" containing all required dependencies, or you can retrieve all dependencies using eg. `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and copy these to the AWS box, too

Comment: You will need to make a shaded-jar with your Hadoop dependencies. And please do not use the old 1.2.1 documentation. And FWIW, most people chose to write Spark nowadays, not Mapreduce